# How to navigate to app if app is installed?

Tags: angular, frontend, mobile-development

When the user click on the link or botton for app and its navigate to that  app if app is install in user device. Otherwise if app is not installed it should navigate to playstore if the device is android and if device is IOS its should navigate to appstore using Angular.
NOTE: WITHOUT INSTALLING PACKAGE OR PLUNGIN

I try some scenarios for chatGPT its not working.